# python: open another file to paste an output value

Tags: python, replace

I have this code to interpolate between the values and return Z value for specific X and Y. I am trying to open another file (world.txt) and paste the value under specific name Nz
The way the file is organised is

```
Nx
5
Ny
0.1
Nz
0.8
```

I am trying to make the code to find Nz and then over write the value under it. But the value is not changing under Nz like the code is not working,
Would you please suggest some ideas of how to fix it?
Best Regards

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import itertools
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xx= 0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55
yy= 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05
zz= 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz, s=0)    
def givemeZ(X,Y):
    return interpolate.bisplev(X,Y,tck)
## to replace the value 
   new_lines = []
previous_line = ''
with open('world.txt', mode = 'r') as f:
    for current_line in f:
        if previous_line == 'Nz':
            new_lines.append(str(givemeZ(0.5,0.01)))
        else:
            new_lines.append(current_line)
        previous_line = current_line

new_text = '\n'.join(new_lines)
```

Comment: You want to edit a line in a file?

Comment: Yes, the code should provide a value and put it in that file

Comment: Are you trying to read Nx and Ny from 'world.txt' and want to write the Nz value back to 'world.txt'?

Comment: No, I am trying to make the code to find Nz and then over write the value under it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are not writing it back, just reading it? Als, you are not iterating over lines when you do

`current_line in f:`, you'd need to do `current_line in f.split('\n'):  # Split on newline.`

You need to do:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import itertools
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xx= 0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55
yy= 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05
zz= 0.75, 0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(xx, yy, zz, s=0)    
def givemeZ(X,Y):
    return interpolate.bisplev(X,Y,tck)
## to replace the value 
   new_lines = []
previous_line = ''
with open('world.txt') as f:  # Mode 'r' is default, no need to specify.
    for current_line in f.read().split('\n'):
        if previous_line == 'Nz':
            new_lines.append(str(givemeZ(0.5,0.01)))
        else:
            new_lines.append(current_line)
        previous_line = current_line

new_text = '\n'.join(new_lines)
open('world.txt', 'w').write(new_text)  # Will save the text to file.
```

Comment: This deleted everything inside the file instead of overwriting one value

Comment: Well then something in your code is wrong, but you will definitely need to run open().write() at the end if you want to save the result.

Comment: I see what it is. You are doing:  ``with open('world.txt', mode = 'r') as f:
    for current_line in f:``, you'd to do do ``with open('world.txt', mode = 'r') as f:
    for current_line in f.split('\n'):`` if you wanted to iterate over lines.

Comment: I updated my answer. No, you are missing the f.split('\n') after opening the file.

Comment: Yes, sorry, youre also not reading the file. Updating my answer, you need to do f.read().split('\n')

Comment: @ alexisdevarennes , Hello Alexis, I have a question, And I am hoping that you would help me, If there are two Nz in the file but with two different values of Z and Z1, How can I do a trick to paste Z under the first Nz and Z1 under the second Nz? ((I cant re-name Nz))